# Using "null" in jQuery functions. Is this okay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, null

My database consists of some entries which are `null` (so they don't affect max, min, etc..).  When I pull all of the data from the database, I need to repopulate form fields with the values.  Using `.val(value)` where `value = null` seems to work without any problems, but I'm not sure if this is a valid way to go about this.  It doesn't say anything in the jQuery documentation (that I can find) about using `null` as parameters to functions.

Edit: Changed `NULL` to `null`.  I was still in PHP mode and that was a typo.

Comment: `NULL` a JavaScript identifier (e.g. you can do `var NULL = "foobar"`). `null` is the JavaScript *keyword* which evaluates to `null`.

Comment: why do people ask questions about jQuery when it's really a javascript question?

Comment: @Juan - because it's *not* a JavaScript question, whether a function handles `null` correctly as a parameter (does it have the desired behavior, any side-effects?) depends on *that* function.

Comment: @pst, no, `null` is a literal (§7.8.1).  The keywords are listed in §7.6.1.1, and `null` is not one of them.

Comment: It *is* a JavaScript function, but not part of the ECMAScript standard library.

Comment: @Juan, it's not an only Javascript question.  I'm asking whether _jQuery_ functions can handle null.

Comment: It's a JavaScript function; one found in the jQuery library. I see nothing wrong with the tags.

Comment: @Nick: now that it doesn't say `NULL`, it can be considered a jquery question, previously you just had an undefined variable, so it required fixing your JavaScript for the question to be about jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different functions handle it in different ways, but for [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) specifically, yes, this is perfectly valid:

```
$(".selector").val(null);
```

[If you look at the `.val()` source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/attributes.js#L232-233), you can see `null` is converted to an empty string, `""` before it's used:

```
if ( val == null ) {
  val = "";
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!  I guess checking the source is the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` a JavaScript identifier (e.g. you can do `var NULL = "foobar"`). `null` is the JavaScript *literal* which evaluates to `null`. (See comments).  Its value is "the sole value of the Null type."

Some (but not all) places in jQuery will behave the same if you pass in `null` or another falsey value such as "" (`null` is one of the false values in JS). You need to check the *specific function documentation* to see what the domain of the function is (e.g. what the accepted input values are).

EDIT: Edited by Matthew Flaschen to reflect comments

Comment: Oops.  I was still in PHP mode with the NULL there.. The specific function documentation doesn't always seem to be clear on whether null or false is acceptable.  For instance, .val() specifies a text string to be used, yet null works ok.  I don't really like to assume things, but I suppose it is a lot less work than converting all the null's to blank strings...

Comment: `null` is not a keyword.  It's a literal and "the sole value of the Null type."

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen Thanks for the correction that `null` is defined as a literal in the specification. I will leave my answer as reference. However, per 4.3.11, the `null value` is "the primitive that represents the intentional absence of any object value", although the `null value`, as you say, *is also* the only member of the Null-type.

Answer (score 0):

This will vary per-function and you should check each one carefully before using it (which of course you do anyway, right?!) to ensure that it behaves in the manner that you expect, but yes, jQuery "works" with `null`.